# Error when creating MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters from tracks uploaded to iTunes

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm using the [Apple Music API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/) to get albums, tracks, playlists, etc from the user's music library. I would like to prepend these songs to the [systemMusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624179-systemmusicplayer)'s queue. This works great for songs that are from the catalog and a `catalogID`. However, if the user uploaded music from their Mac to the Cloud Music Library, it refuses to queue. Let's take a look at the request, response, and the code.

#### The Issue

The URL request to the Apple Music API looks like this:

```
https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/library/albums/\(id)?include=tracks
```

This returns the album with the requested id. If we look into the album's tracks, we get the following JSON response (I replaced irrelevant details like the song and artist):

```
{
  "id" : "i.9oJNEa6Iz66G2l",
  "attributes" : {
    "genreNames" : [
      "Alternative"
    ],
    "discNumber" : 0,
    "hasLyrics" : false,
    "albumName" : "The Album Name",
    "artwork" : {
      "url" : "thealbumurl",
      "width" : null,
      "height" : null
    },
    "durationInMillis" : 866379,
    "artistName" : "The artist name",
    "trackNumber" : 1,
    "playParams" : {
      "reporting" : false,
      "isLibrary" : true,
      "id" : "i.9oJNEa6Iz66G2l",
      "kind" : "song"
    },
    "name" : "The song title"
  },

  "href" : "\/v1\/me\/library\/songs\/i.9oJNEa6Iz66G2l",
  "type" : "library-songs"
}
```

Finally, I get the `playParams` dictionary, initialize MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters with it, and [prepend](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/2817538-prepend) it to the queue:

```
if let givenParams = attributes["playParams"].dictionaryObject {
    // Returns ["id": i.9oJNEa6Iz66G2l, "reporting": 0, "kind": song, "isLibrary": 1]
    let parameters = MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters(dictionary: givenParams)
    let descriptor = MPMusicPlayerPlayParametersQueueDescriptor(playParametersQueue: [parameters])
    player.prepend(descriptor)
}
```

As I said, this works fine if the playParams are from a catalog song, and usually I can convert library songs into catalog songs *unless* the user uploaded the song to iTunes, themselves. Then, I'm thrown an error

`[SDKPlayback] prependQueueDescriptor failed error: Error Domain=MPMusicPlayerControllerErrorDomain Code=6 "Failed to prepare queue for prepend" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Failed to prepare queue for prepend}`

#### What I've Learned

I've found what I think might be the issue. I want to look closely at the `playParams` dictionary given (as seen above):

```
"playParams" : {
    "reporting" : false,
    "isLibrary" : true,
    "id" : "i.9oJNEa6Iz66G2l",
    "kind" : "song"
 }
```

And here is the playParams of a catalog song so you can see the difference:

```
"playParams" : {
    "kind" : "song",
    "id" : "1596173449"
 }
```

Which, as I've said, works perfectly. From what I can tell, [`MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayerplayparameters/) doesn't like it when the id starts with `i.` as seen in the response's playParams. Even though I'm giving `MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters` the rest of the dictionary containing "isLibrary" and the corresponding value. The whole purpose of the API's playParams is exactly for using it with `MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters` as stated by it's own [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayerplayparametersqueuedescriptor) saying

> A set of properties and methods used to modify how items are played, based on play parameters returned from MusicKit API results.

I am about to just not allow users to play songs they've uploaded themselves, which of course I don't want to do. What can I try next?

Comment: Why do you think "doesn't like it when the id starts with i"? And what's the type of 'id' in MPMusicPlayerPlayParameters?